# Data validation for regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to add validation like numbers and comma and numbers

Ex: my case needs to accept

```
111232
12323, 123234
12324, 12323, 123234 


[RegularExpression(@"^([1-9,;]*$)||^([1-9]*$)", ErrorMessage = "Please enter single Order or for multiple enter with comma separator.")]
public string Order { get; set; }
```

Comment: string input = "111232 12323, 123234 12324, 12323, 123234";
            string pattern = @"\d+ \d+[\s,]?|\d+[\s,]?";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

Comment: Are you excluding `0`s intentionally in your character sets or are you just concerned about the first digit being `0`?

Comment: Use `^[0-9]+(?:\s[0-9]+)*$`

Answer (score 0):

This needs to solve your issue

```
^(\d+,?\s*)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following.

```
^(\d+)(,\s*\d+)*$
```

[Sample](https://regex101.com/r/tRNRW3/2)